# Jquery validation if its empty, numeric or value higher that 13

Tags: jquery, validation

Where is error why div wont show, what i want to do is check is numeric is not empty and value is lower that 13

js

```
(function($) {     
if($('#month-holder').length){
$('#month-holder').on("blur", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var month = $("#month-holder").val();
    if (typeof month != "undefined"){
        if(!$.isNumeric(month)){
            if (parseInt(month) > 13) {
                $('#month-error').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#month-holder').addClass("invalid");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $('#month-error').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#month-holder').removeClass("invalid");
    }
});
}
})(jQuery);
```

css

```
input.invalid {    
border: 1px solid red;    
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #e4e4e4;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #e4e4e4;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #e4e4e4;
}
#month-error{
display: none;
}
.error{ color: #f00; padding: 5px 0 0}
```

html

```
 <input type="text" name="month-holder" id="month-holder" class="input-txt width-65" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" pattern="\d*" x-autocompletetype="month-holder" required autocomplete="off">
 <div id="month-error"  class="error clearfix">Error</div>
```

Can any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

change your conditon

```
  if(!$.isNumeric(month)){
```

to

```
   if($.isNumeric(month)){
```

your current implementaion will not work if you first input invalid data and then delete it and retype valid data it will not remove error messages.

simply you can do this like this:

```
(function($) {     
if($('#month-holder').length){
$('#month-holder').on("blur", function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var month = $("#month-holder").val();
     if ( $.isNumeric(month) && parseInt(month) < 13) {
                $('#month-error').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#month-holder').removeClass("invalid");

       }  
      else
      {
        $('#month-error').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#month-holder').addClass("invalid");
      }
});
}
})(jQuery);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/661/

Comment: @Digital Legend : did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.isNumeric(month) && parseInt(month) > 13){
            $('#month-error').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#month-holder').addClass("invalid");
        }

        else
        {
            $('#month-error').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#month-holder').removeClass("invalid");
        }
```

Comment: still your logic is wrong! `parseInt(month) > 13` ?